# How do I get rid of My so called bitcoin account

Tags: client

I was recently contacted by Brian from Bitcoin telling me I have registered but I did not. How do I delete the account and for them to stop phoning me

Comment: What account, where? It is likely a scam. The answer by Meni Rosenfeld is probably good advice.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing. Either you misunderstood this person, or he was lying.

Bitcoin is a decentralized digital currency. It is not a company with representatives that contact you or that you can have an account with.

There are companies that provide Bitcoin-related services and you may have registered with one, but based on your description this is not likely the case.

Probably you are the target of some form of scam. Scams have existed long before Bitcoin, and it's quite common that scammers call people and ask for their money under all kinds of false pretenses. The fact that this particular scammer has chosen to specify "Bitcoin" as a pretense alters nothing.

If this persists, contacting your local law enforcement could be prudent.